# How do I diagnose patches of dead grass?

Tags: grass

I have small, miscellaneous patches of dead grass, even though we have had a very wet spring, and I want to figure out why the grass is dying in random locations.

The dead patches are sometimes in streaks that are mixed in with healthy green lawn, and other times they are circular and about 3-6 inches in diameter. In general, the lawn looks good and is very healthy.

I understand that one possible cause is insects eating the roots. To investigate this do I just dig a square of turf, say 10" x 10", then lift it up and see what bugs are there or is there more to it than that? What is the basic diagonostic procedure for my problem?

Comment: Possibly grubs?  Do you have a dog?  Hard to say without pictures and a location.

Comment: @Steve-o169 Read the question. I am not asking for a diagnosis. I am asking HOW to do a diagnosis.

Comment: Plenty of results from a [simple search](http://bfy.tw/OLO1).   As I said, location can be pretty useful on this sort of thing, but by all means, go ahead and tear up chunks of your yard.